# How to load image in Action Script?

Tags: actionscript-3, action

How to load image in Action Script ?

i have used the following code but image was not loaded.`var ldr:Loader = new Loader();

```
 var url:String = "D:\BlackBerry\workspace\SoundTest\blackberry-tablet-icon.png.bmp"; 
 var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url); 
 ldr.load(urlReq); 
 addChild(ldr);
 stage.nativeWindow.visible = true;`
```

Please help ?

Comment: this may have to do with the format you're trying to load... you could try loading this instead: blackberry-tablet-icon.png

Comment: I have implemented backslashes but melt down again, same result image did not came. here is my code :    loader.load(new URLRequest("D:\\BlackBerry\\workspace\\SoundTest\\assets\\sample.jpg"));

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the errors that this loader gives:

```
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, onStatus);

function onError(e:IOErrorEvent):void{
    trace(e);
}
function onStatus(e:HTTPStatusEvent):void{
    trace(e);
}
```

Now you can filter the errors out and search on the web the specific arrow this loader gives.

I guess its a security error. Flash prevents to load images outside his domain(exception is debug version in Flash cs5) 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/SecurityError.html

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't find the error, even i tried giving different paths and that also not helped me                                    var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("C:/Users/ramesh_bhamidipati/Desktop/Ramesh/sample.jpg");